# Windows Server AppFabric Custom Configuration Provider Issues

Tags: azure, appfabric, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

UPDATE

Here is the link to the custom provider code - http://www.gurpreetsohal.com/configurationprovider.zip

I have managed to use reflector to step further into the Microsoft AppFabric dlls and I have found the place where the exception occurs.

[image]

The exception is caused on the WaitForStatus method - The service is definitely in the starting state, it just never reaches the started state within the timeout value.

The default timeout value is 60 seconds. I have increased this to 10 minutes, same problem.

---

The scenario is:

1)Working in a workgroup environment 
This means that AppFabric will not allow a SQL Server source to store the configuration file, so you are left to a fileshare or creating a custom configuration provider.

I chose to do the latter and wrote up an implementation using the ICustomProvider interface provided, using blobstorage.

This all seems to work fine, the configuration can be created/modified deleted correctly - the configuration wizard works fine.

The problem is when I run the Start-CacheCluster in powershell, the AppFabric Caching Service hangs at the state of Starting.

Powershell then throws an error:

[image]
However, if I manually start the service from services.msc - it works fine no problem, pretty much instantly.

To make sure that this isn't an environment issue, I have configured AppFabric to use the fileshare for the configuration and it has worked fine without any problem.

I then started looking to see what this powershell command actually does and decompiled the dll.

It got me as far as this:
[image]

currentAdmin.StartCluster(new ProgressDelegate(this, (IntPtr) this.StartClusterDelegate), new WriteErrorDelegate(this, (IntPtr) this.WriteErrorRecord), this.QuorumTimeout, this.HostTimeout);

I cant step in any further and am stuck.

I have tried both Azure Tables and Blob Storage to try and get this to work

Help!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since it uses a non standard port, I would make sure this port is open on all the nodes in the cluster. A timeout exception could be a firewall blocking the non standard port.

I looked at the screenshot of your decompiled code, and it looks like it is just throwing the timeout, like in the error.

Thanks,

Comment: Firewalls are down. The basic configuration I am trying is a single node, so it is also the admin node.

Comment: Also, in the original question, I have mentioned that I used the standard fileshare method, which worked without any problems!!

Comment: @warpcore. If you can, it mightn't be a bad idea to throw up the code for your custom provider. Perhaps there is an issue there.

Comment: Good idea Nick! I am wondering if because this is a cluster resource it does not update the ServiceController status but the state changes on the cluster resource instead. I am not sure exactly which .NET API to use but you may have to make your custom provider cluster aware.

The cluster Powershell methods might give you some clues if you look at the source for them: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461009.aspx